# edit file from internal storage

Tags: java, android, file

How can I edit the content of a file located on the internal storage in my Android app.

I want to erase the whole content and then write to the file again, instead of appending data to the current content.

Here's my code to read and write:

```
package com.example.cargom;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;


public class FileManager {

    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    FileInputStream inputStream;

    public void writeToFile(Context context, String fileName, String data) {
        try {
            outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readFromFile(Context context, String fileName) {
        String data = "";
        int c;

        try {
            inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                data = data + Character.toString((char) c);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting errors in logcat or is it just not working?

Comment: Your code is not appending data to an existing file but erases the file first as far as i can see.

Comment: Oh yeah I can see that. Thank you!

Comment: Moreover there is nothing in your code that edits something. You are not editing the readed data. You are just writing a new file with data we have no idea of. This has not much to do with editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is already doing what you rquire. It first erases the contents of the file and then writes on it. For further understanding,

When you initiate your stream with **MODE_PRIVATE**, the second time when you try to write the file, the contents that are already in the file gets erased and the new contents are written.

```
    outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

When you use **MODE_APPEND**, the contents that are already there stays and the new contents will be appended to the file.

```
    outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

For more reference and detailed knowledge on dealing with files in Internal storage, I recommend you to watch the below three short videos which gives you detailed description with demo.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jswr6tkv8ro&index=4&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGxHphBjTBk&index=5&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMcrj_To18k&index=6&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT

Hope it helps! Any more questions, please comment below.

Comment: @AlonsoArellano Accept the answer by clicking the tick by the side of the answer if this answered your question and hence it would be knowledgeable for another user with the same question.

Comment: @codePG please reread the question and realise that you did not address the problem at all.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for claiming that I answered the question. In the question I can see that its a class there to manage file read and write. I hope atleast I have clarified the different modes that can be used and there purpose. I had a feeling explaining the above would let him/her differentiate the different modes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the file first with:

```
File f = new File(filename);
if(f.exists()){
    f.delete();
}
```

And then create a new one with same path/name and write to it.
I'm assuming that your `filename` is the path to the file on the device.

But probably I'm not getting your real problem?