# The correct way to edit internal java files in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to implement changes in the functionality of GestureDetector.java. The easy way should be just to create a custom GestureDetector that extends from the original one, and to implement the changes:

```
public class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {
    public CustomGestureDetector(OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler) {
        super(listener, handler);
    }

    public CustomGestureDetector(OnGestureListener listener) {
        super(listener);
    }

    public CustomGestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener) {
        super(context, listener);
    }

    public CustomGestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler) {
        super(context, listener, handler);
    }

    public CustomGestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler, boolean unused) {
        super(context, listener, handler, unused);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnDoubleTapListener(OnDoubleTapListener onDoubleTapListener) {
        super.setOnDoubleTapListener(onDoubleTapListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContextClickListener(OnContextClickListener onContextClickListener) {
        super.setContextClickListener(onContextClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIsLongpressEnabled(boolean isLongpressEnabled) {
        super.setIsLongpressEnabled(isLongpressEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongpressEnabled() {
        return super.isLongpressEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onGenericMotionEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

But I would like to override the function onTouchEvent and implement very specific changes so I cannot just implement them here and then call the super class, nor take the whole code for this function and copy it here because it relies on other variables.

In such case, should I create an alternative GestureDetector and then import the custom one in my project, instead of the regular one?

If it matters, the default behavior of the detector is to disable the scrolling function when long pressed it triggered:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mInLongPress || mInContextClick) {
            break;
        }
```

But I would like it to still fire while the user is long pressing, and then scrolling.

Also, another problem is that I cannot just copy the code from GestureDetector.java to my own class in my project, since it actually contains many errors and then it won't compile anymore.

Comment: Internal java file edit check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26335107/10967323).

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but the link looks irrelevant, I'm looking to edit a file in my project, not to deal with functionality of my app being able to change files

Comment: you are right you can't change extended GestureDetector .